# Error in ram testing that does not seem erroneous

Tags: memory

I am currently running a 2012 iMac as a Ubuntu server, and I tried to upgrade the RAM. Macs are picky about their RAM, so I had to make sure it was in the right slots. Java would freeze up the full machine shortly after starting my program, with the error being linked online to memory. Running MemTest returned this:

```
Expected:
0000000200xxxxxx
Found: 
0000000300xxxxxx
```

With all the digits after the 3 correct, consistently.

Is this faulty RAM, or am I doing something wrong?

One thing to note is that the supported RAM is DDR3 in a laptop form factor, while I have put in DDR3-L RAM, but according to Google, that's fine.

I also have had no issues with this RAM on other systems before now.

Comment: Everything you describe suggests the problem is the memory module. If you have ran software to test your memory, and it routinely comes back with errors, then the module is indeed the problem.

Comment: "According to Google that's fine" - evidently this is not the case.

Comment: Judging by the new account posting a comment as an answer it appears that you have lost access to the account that created this question. This can happen if you regularly clear cookies or change machines and will result in you being unable to edit, comment on, or accept answers to your question. Either you need to go back to the machine and browser you originally asked the question from, or you should register a proper account and use the [contact](https://superuser.com/contact) form at the bottom of the page selecting "I need to merge accounts" so that you can regain control of this question.

Comment: It would be valuable if you included more specifics.  What is the make and model of each of the RAM.  How many and which memory slots are filled?  What is the individual capacity of each stick?  What are the actual complete memory specifications provided by Apple for that model?

Comment: If the memory module (aka stick) seems to work in other systems, then the first thing to suspect is the memory socket (aka slot). Try rearranging the memory modules; does the fault follow a module (fault at different addresses) or stay with the socket (fault at same addresses)?

Comment: So program errors out due to memory error, memory tester confirms a memory error but you still doubt a memory issue.